# How to make the tags appear the old way on Mavericks?

Tags: macos, finder-tag

Is there a way to make the folders tagged in any color (red, blue, purple, etc.) appear in a more visible way than the `OSX 10.9` way?

[image]

For instance, on `OSX 10.8`, the whole title of the item was colored.

A long time ago (`System 7`), even the color of the folder was changed.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no officially supported way to do this (and no unofficially supported hack that re-enables it either).  The behaviour of Tags in Mavericks as compared to Labels in every previous version of OS X is very different, and you cannot pick and choose elements to work in one way and have the rest to work in another, it's all or nothing I'm afraid, so if you are on Mavericks the best you can do is hope for a feature as part of a future OS update that adds extended options to tags.  I'm sure further tag options will be forthcoming, as it's essentially a V1 feature at present, and maybe this will be one of them.